# Blender Python: How do you automate creation of duplicate objects along many curves?

Tags: bezier-curves, parent, groups

I'm trying to automate creation of many objects along many paths (curves). I've tried using parenting, Dupliframes and Modifiers but in both cases I'm blocked by my lack of experience with scripts, especially how to work with groups of objects.

What is required in a script to go through all the objects in one group and create duplicates along the corresponding paths in another group? Example?

Comment: So you have N number of objects and M number of curves, how exactly do you want to distribute the objects along the curves? This is the first step towards the solution whether it involves python or modifiers.

Comment: To be specific, I have the same number of objects and curves - one master object (a sphere) to duplicate along each curve. I can do what I want simply enough - one at a time - with dupliframes or using the array and curve modifiers. Spacing along the curves is simple and uniform. I can't figure out the syntax for the For statement to work with two corresponding groups (lists). (Or to apply the two modifiers if I use that method.)